# Finding the number of moves a knight can perform while standing on a given square

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, chess

This is a problem from CodeSignal which can be founded over [here](https://app.codesignal.com/arcade/intro/level-11/pwRLrkrNpnsbgMndb)

Here is an image on what we have to do:

[image]

### Code

```py
def map(cell):
    new_cell1 = ''
    
    for i in cell:
        if i == 'a':
            new_cell1 += '1'
        if i == 'b':
            new_cell1 += '2'
        if i == 'c':
            new_cell1 += '3'
        if i == 'd':
            new_cell1 += '4'
        if i == 'e':
            new_cell1 += '5'
        if i == 'f':
            new_cell1 += '6'
        if i == 'g':
            new_cell1 += '7'
        if i == 'h':
            new_cell1 += '8'
            
    new_cell1 += cell[-1]
    return new_cell1
    
def chessKnight(cell):
    cell = map(cell)
    num_of_moves = 0
    
    if (int(cell[0])+1 <= 8 and int(cell[0])+1 > 0) and (int(cell[1])+2 <= 8 and int(cell[1])+2 > 0):
        num_of_moves += 1
        
    if (int(cell[0])-1 <= 8 and int(cell[0])-1 > 0) and (int(cell[1])+2 <= 8 and int(cell[1])+2 > 0):
        num_of_moves += 1
        
    if (int(cell[0])+1 <= 8 and int(cell[0])+1 > 0) and (int(cell[1])-2 <= 8 and int(cell[1])-2 > 0):
        num_of_moves += 1
        
    if (int(cell[0])-1 <= 8 and int(cell[0])-1 > 0) and (int(cell[1])-2 <= 8 and int(cell[1])-2 > 0):
        num_of_moves += 1
        
    if (int(cell[0])+2 <= 8 and int(cell[0])+2 > 0) and (int(cell[1])+1 <= 8 and int(cell[1])+1 > 0):
        num_of_moves += 1
    
    if (int(cell[0])-2 <= 8 and int(cell[0])-2 > 0) and (int(cell[1])+1 <= 8 and int(cell[1])+1 > 0):
        num_of_moves += 1
    
    if (int(cell[0])+2 <= 8 and int(cell[0])+2 > 0) and (int(cell[1])-1 <= 8 and int(cell[1])-1 > 0):
        num_of_moves += 1
    
    if (int(cell[0])-2 <= 8 and int(cell[0])-2 > 0) and (int(cell[1])-1 <= 8 and int(cell[1])-1 > 0):
        num_of_moves += 1
        
    return num_of_moves
```

### Question

The Code works as expected and returns the right answer, but I have just put a bunch of `if` conditions which doesn't look nice to me. Is there any way to implement the problem but without so much `if` blocks?

Comment: Please note that when you link a question  from code signal, the question is locked for all of those who haven't solved the first problems, due to which the higher-level questions are locked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Never use existing function names for new functions

Python already has a function called `map()` 
Defining your new `map()` function can cause a lot of confusion, and undefined behaviour in your program.

## By cheating

Since you have asked for an alternate solution, here it is

Being a chess engine developer, I would never calculate something trivial like the number of knight attacks since a simple array of size `64` with the pre-calculated ones can easily work. All you need is a simple function that converts a square like `a1` to 0 and `h8` to 63.

Here is the implementation,

```py
def str_sq_to_int(sq):
    return (ord(sq[0])-97) + ((ord(sq[1])-49) * 8);

def knightAttacks(cell):
    attacks = [
        2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2,
        3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3,
        4, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 4,
        4, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 4,
        4, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 4,
        4, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 6, 4,
        3, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 4, 3,
        2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2
    ]
    return attacks[str_sq_int(cell)]
```

The explanation is simple, the function `str_sq_to_int()` takes a square like `'a1'` and returns an index using the [ASCII value of the character](http://www.asciitable.com/) to calculate the index. You can also use a simple dictionary to map each square to an index, but this one is easy

Then, it uses a pre-calculated set of values, to return the correct answer.

Comment: Lol. This answer is very cool,

Comment: @fartgeek yeah , I kind of copy pasted the str_to_int function from my chess engine though xD. I would recommend bit manipulation but since it's python, doesn't make sense

Comment: To improve this answer, I would suggest making `str_sq_to_int`, `ord` and `sq` more explicit and making the casing consistent. Also the magic numbers (97, 49, 8) could use some names.

Comment: @RaimundKrämer Is that why you downvoted? It is good advice, I will remove the magic numbers but I'm not sure what name I could get for them since they are based on the ascii values

Comment: @RaimundKrämer I'm a little unsure as to what you expect more in this answer, may i suggest you edit it yourself? I would like to see what I missed that deserved a downvote

Answer (score 0):

Alright. This is an interesting question. If you think about it, the moves of a knight have a few conditions (excluding checks and whether a friendly piece is on the destination square):

- The move has to be on the board (this is one is obvious)
- The absolute value of the distance moved to the side subtracted from the absolute value of the distanced moved up must either equal one or -1.
- The absolute value of the distance moved to the side must be one or two.
- The absolute value of the distance moved up or down must be either one or two.

The code is as follows :

```
def knight_move_counter(position_on_board):
    possibleMoves = 0
    # here we could use ASCII values to convert the letters to numbers, but a dict is easier to visualize
    letterToNumbers = {
        "a" : 0,
        "b" : 1,
        "c" : 2,
        "d" : 3,
        "e" : 4,
        "f" : 5,
        "g" : 6,
        "h" : 7
    }
    start_letter = letterToNumbers[position_on_board[0]]
    start_number = int(position_on_board[1]) - 1 # note that this line and the preceding one will only work if they are valid algebraic notation.
    for iterator in range(8):
        for second_iterator in range(8): # these two for loops assure our answers will be on the board.
            if abs( abs(start_letter - iterator) - abs(start_number - second_iterator)) == 1: # point #2
                if abs(start_letter - iterator) == 1 or abs(start_letter - iterator) == 2: # point #3
                    if abs(start_number - second_iterator) == 1 or abs(start_number - second_iterator) == 2: # point #4
                        possibleMoves += 1
    return possibleMoves


print(knight_move_counter("a1")) # you can replace the "a1" with whatever you would like, as long as it is valid algebraic notation.
```

Comment: [this](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Knight_Pattern) article on knight patterns is really cool